# Loop Tools Addon

Tags: add-on

Cant find a loop tools addon. On the [offical page](https://sites.google.com/site/bartiuscrouch/looptools) only link on [empty directory](https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-blender/). Im searching everywhere. Can anyone give me link?

Comment: Afaik, LoopTools are built-in now. In 2.76b they are at least. No need to downoad them. Try searching LoopTools in Add-ons tab in User Preferences.

Answer (score 6):

Looptool is actually bundled with Blender now (it has been for a while, but I'm not sure quite how long).

To enable it, go into the users preferences and then addons. From there, use the search box to search "loop" and then enable the addon.
[image]

To use it, in edit mode, press <kbd>W</kbd> and then go to the looptools drop down.

Answer (score 1):

if you have latest builds of Blender, loop tools is included:
on edit mode, press W, loop tools

https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Modeling/LoopTools

Comment: Thaks bro's. Im so stupid that can't think this so easy)