# How do I shift a vertex to establish a single, flat surface on a quad?

Tags: mesh, vertices, geometry

One thing that I've noticed when drawing quads is that, if a single surface cannot be established using the vertex arrangement (for example, if you add the default plane and raise a single vertex to 1 on the Z-axis), Blender will treat it a quad (subsurf works fine with it and will smooth it out into a hyperbolic surface) but render it as two conjoined tris (prior to the subsurf).

Now, I'm fairly certain that I should avoid this in most cases and would want to fix it if it does occur. In my example above, I could obviously just shift the vertex back to 0 on the Z-axis, because the surface is completely flat. However, if I were to rotate this quad, I would be in a situation where moving the vertex to establish a flat surface would require very precise changes to the X, Y, and Z positions.

I was wondering if there is some feature of Blender or a technique to adjust vertices exactly that the quad is absolutely flat, even if the quad is rotated.

P.S. I apologize for the very technical  and possibly pedantic style of writing. Because I want to ensure the question is communicated clearly, I felt that it was necessary to be scrupulous.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35193/how-to-flatten-a-non-planar-face-to-a-targeted-plane

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extracted from [my answer here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/119930/30849), here is another scripted option. In contrary
to [Blender Dadaist's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/119924/30849), this method creates a planar quad, by only moving the active vertex. <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> select the three vertices of the quad, which are not supposed to change, then <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> select the vertice of the quad, which you wish to change, marking it as the active vertex.

[image: flatten vertex]

The script registers an operator and places it in the menu: *Mesh > Vertices > Flatten Vertex* with the hotkey <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>.

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Flatten Vertex Onto Face",
    "category": "Object",
}

import bpy
import bmesh


class ObjectFlattenVertex(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Flatten Vertex Onto Face"""
    bl_idname = "edit_mesh.flatten_vertex"
    bl_label = "Flatten Vertex"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    influence = bpy.props.FloatProperty(name='Influence', subtype='PERCENTAGE', default=1, min=0, max=1)

    def execute(self, context):
        if (context.object == None):
            self.report({'ERROR_INVALID_CONTEXT'}, "This is only possible with vertices of an object.")
            return {'CANCELLED'}
        me = context.object.data

        if me.is_editmode:
            bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
        else:
            bm = bmesh.new()
            bm.from_mesh(me)

        for elem in bm.select_history:
            if (isinstance(elem, bmesh.types.BMVert) == False):
                self.report({'ERROR_INVALID_INPUT'}, "Select vertices only.")
                return {'CANCELLED'}
        if len(bm.select_history) != 4:
            self.report({'ERROR_INVALID_INPUT'}, "Select exactly four vertices.")
            return {'CANCELLED'}
        if (bm.select_history.active == None):
            self.report({'ERROR_INVALID_INPUT'}, "Require an active vertex.")
            return {'CANCELLED'}
        active = bm.select_history.active
        # get only selected vertices
        p1, p2, origin = [v.co for v in bm.select_history if v != active]
        a = active.co - origin
        # normal
        n =  (p1 - origin).cross(p2 - origin)
        # projected
        prj =  n.cross(a.cross(n) / n.length) / n.length
        active.co = self.influence * prj + (1 - self.influence) * a + origin

        if bm.is_wrapped:
            bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me, False, False)
        else:
            bm.to_mesh(me)
            me.update()
        return {'FINISHED'}


def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(ObjectFlattenVertex.bl_idname)

addon_keymaps = []

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ObjectFlattenVertex)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_edit_mesh_vertices.append(menu_func)

    wm = bpy.context.window_manager # keymap
    kc = wm.keyconfigs.addon # background mode check
    if kc:
        km = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name = "Window",space_type='EMPTY', region_type='WINDOW')
        kmi = km.keymap_items.new(ObjectFlattenVertex.bl_idname, type = "M", shift=True, ctrl=True, value = "PRESS")
        addon_keymaps.append(km)

def unregister():
    for km, kmi in addon_keymaps:
        km.keymap_items.remove(kmi)
    addon_keymaps.clear()

    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ObjectFlattenVertex)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_edit_mesh_vertices.remove(menu_func)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

#### Some math

At `# get only selected vertices` the selected three vertice's coordinates (not the active) are stored in `p1`, `p2` and `origin`. The active vertex is stored in `active`.

The two directional vectors of the plane are `p1 - origin` and `p2 - origin`. The "base" of the plane is at `origin`.
Thus, the normal vector of the plane is `n =  (p1 - origin).cross(p2 - origin)` (cross product).

The active vertex's position *relativ* to the origin is at `a = active.co - origin`.
Now, `a` has to be projected onto the plane with the normal vector `n`. This is explained [here](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/elements/plane/lineOnPlane/index.htm).
[image]

In case the link goes down, I will excerpt the math in a very condensed form, but it's just projecting the vector a onto the plane.

```
a1  ...        a projected onto the plane
|a| ...        magnitude of a
θ   ...        angle between a and n

d   ...        directional vector pointing to a (normalized)
d = (a / |a|) × ((b × a)/|(b × a)|)
d = norm(a) × norm(b × a)

l   ...        magnitude of the projected vector
l = |a| · sin(θ)

a1 = l · d
a1 = |a| · sin(θ) · norm(a) × norm(b × a)

Given: norm(a) × norm(b) = norm(a × b) · sin(θ)
a1 = norm(a) · norm(n) × norm(a) × norm(n)

a1 = n × (a × n / |n|) / |n|
```

The shift the projected vector `a1` by the position of the `origin`.

Comment: Neat solution indeed! But I need some time to understand it. Would you mind explaining `prj =  n.cross(a.cross(n) / n.length) / n.length` or maybe just give a pointer where the relevant information can be found? Thank you.

Comment: @BlenderDadaist See edit.

Answer (score 5):

If you only care about planar faces in general, then there's an automatic way for that by selecting **Mesh > Clean Up > Make Planar Faces**.

If you really want to only move a specific vertex of the quad, you can

1. move the 3D Cursor to one of the three other vertices (Select the vertex, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to Selected*) and switch to *Pivot Point* > *3D Cursor* (<kbd>.</kbd> key)
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd>-select all three vertices that should define your plane and should not move
3. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to define a custom [*Transform Orientation*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/de/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/orientations.html)
4. Select the vertex that you want to move and scale it locally along the Z-axis of the new transform orientation: <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> `0` <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: I knew it had to be somewhere ... of _course_, my meshes never _need_ cleaning up... so I've never found that button   ¦  l

Answer (score 4):

[image: Rotate vertex]

This should be possible via python. Basically you rotate the vertex in question around the origin by the difference between the normals of the two planar faces of the non-planar quad.

```
import bmesh
import bpy

bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(bpy.context.object.data)
vert = [v for v in bm.verts if v.select == True][0]
face = vert.link_faces[0] #Assuming single linked face
i = [i for i in range(0, len(face.verts)) if face.verts[i] == vert][0]
next  = face.verts[(i+1)%4]#quad
prev  = face.verts[(i-1)%4]
opp  = face.verts[(i+2)%4]
f1 = bm.faces.new([prev, vert, next])
f2 = bm.faces.new([next, opp, prev])
f1.normal_update()
f2.normal_update()
quat = f1.normal.rotation_difference(f2.normal)
bmesh.ops.rotate(bm, cent=(0,0,0), matrix=quat.to_matrix(), verts=[vert])
bm.faces.remove(f1)
bm.faces.remove(f2)
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT', toggle = False)
```

Comment: Interesting take, cool re using the modulus to get other verts from index.  Is it worth noting that this method using  rotation preserves edge length.  Method [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/35763/15543) translates vert to closest point on  plane defined by other 3 face verts.  Could use `i = face.verts[:].index(vert)`