# Rendering artifacts in flat shaded geometry only visible in cycles. What causes it?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, artifacts

I'm doing the Blender course from [Polygon Runway](https://polygonrunway.com/), and in my second attempt I ran into some odd artifacts that I can't pin down. They are only visible when rendering in cycles, and I'm quite sure there's an issue with my geometry, but I don't understand what it is. I've also uploaded the file in question here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/dx54f64w9yyt5v6/CyclesArtifacts.blend?dl=0

- There don't seem to be any overlapping things, as far as I can see
- The face appears to be flat
- I tried merging duplicate vertices and the like, to no avail
- I deleted the face to see if anything else showed, but also negative

It's probably something obvious, so I hope someone here can point me to the issue :)

[image: cycles visual artifacts example]

Comment: you are dealing with non-planar geometry. Maybe these links can help you: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119874/how-can-i-manually-fix-nonplanar-geometry and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56755/flat-quads-or-why-is-my-mesh-so-funky

Comment: Thanks :D If you post it as an answer I can also accept it. Also is there a way to see this outside of cycles?

Comment: All 3D programs will suffer from this. You cannot "bend" faces. You need to subdivide them to have curvature.

Comment: Oh now I get it. I didn't look at it from the top. I was under the impression that they were all aligned, but they are slightly shifted. Thanks!